# ImageJ batch image conversion

Tags: imagej

I am trying to batch convert 200+ raw .img files using a batch script in ImageJ. My script:

```bs
//-----------Code starts here--------------------- 
dir1 = getDirectory("path/source"); 
dir2 = getDirectory("path/target"); 
list = getFileList(dir1); 
setBatchMode(true); 

 for (i=0; i<list.length; i++) { 
      showProgress(i+1, list.length); 
      if(endsWith(list[i],".IMG")) 
         run("Raw...", open=["+dir1+list[i]+"] image=[16-bit Unsigned] width=2048 height=2048 offset=359 number=1 gap=0"); 
      else 
         open(dir1+list[i]); 
      saveAs(format, dir2+list[i]); 
      close(); 
   }
```

However, when I try running it I get the following error:

I am not sure why however, as I do have a ; closing the line...

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message is misleading, because you're missing a quotation mark (") at the beginning of your second parameter to `run()`:

```bs
run("Raw...", "open=["+dir1+list[i]+"] image=[16-bit Unsigned] width=2048 height=2048 offset=359 number=1 gap=0");
```

The `<` and `>` characters in the error message are indicating the position where the parser finds something unexpected.

I edited your original code to include syntax highlighting, which facilitates finding this kind of errors. Fiji's [script editor](http://imagej.net/Using_the_Script_Editor) includes syntax highlighting and is recommended when working with ImageJ macros.

In general, ImageJ-specific questions are more likely to be answered in time when posted on the dedicated forum: http://forum.imagej.net/